# Strange new rules added to my iptables config... Was my server hacked?

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw, hacking

Today, I listed my iptables for a routine check -- and discovered two strange UFW rules that I don't remember setting up myself, referring to two specific IP addresses that I can't identify:

```
-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d 239.255.255.250/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
```

This is kind of scary. Did someone manage to hack into my server and add these rules? If not, what happened?

*(And if some malicious agent did hack into my firewall, why would they use ports 5353 and 1900, that aren't being forwarded by my router??)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting `man ufw`:

```
NOTES
       On installation, ufw is disabled with  a  default  incoming  policy  of
       deny,  a  default forward policy of deny, and a default outgoing policy
       of allow, with stateful tracking for NEW connections for  incoming  and
       forwarded  connections.  In addition to the above, a default ruleset is
       put in place that does the following:

       [ ... ]

       - ACCEPT mDNS (zeroconf/bonjour/avahi 224.0.0.251 for IPv4 and ff02::fb
       for IPv6) for service discovery (INPUT)

       - ACCEPT UPnP (239.255.255.250 for IPv4 and ff02::f for IPv6) for ser‐
       vice discovery (INPUT)
```

So these two rules you are seeing are part of `ufw`'s default settings and allow mDNS and UPnP services to work.

Comment: Aha! Right, I should have checked the manpage. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Googling says that those IP addresses are related to Simple Service Discovery Protocol (SSDP)/uPnP and iTunes.  So it is likely that these rules are related to software you installed and relate to sharing information on a LAN. `whois` doesn't return any information for either IP.

See

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483717/what-is-the-multicast-doing-on-224-0-0-251

and

https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSDP